# How to change default save folder DCIM\Camera to any folder name and used MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

How to Specify folder Like Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/mypic";

And take many picture with ( MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA)

Briefly ( in one word )
     How to change default save folder DCIM\Camera  to any folder name 
It's work with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE to send uri 
But it take one pic only I need to take many pic as I can this is the problemn'

Notes ...... 
   the App [Camera Folder] make this work but i don't no How it's Work
   you select folder and Press camera Button and Take photo as you can and all photo be in this folder that you selected ...

Thank you For Your Help

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. Your app can launch the Camera with INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA intent, but it has no control over the way the Camera app will work.

Luckily, when (and if) the Camera app is closed and control is back to your app, you can scan the MediaStore for new images, wherever they are on the device. Your app should have r/w access to these images, and then it can simply move all of them (or some of them) to alternative directory.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in responding thank you for your answer

Comment: I really do what you say before to take copy photo from camera folder to my folder and delete the photo in camera folder but the photo in damage and some phone when plugin the cable to computer can't see the phone i must make setup factory

Comment: Please explain the *damage* situation in detail. Does this happen when the device is USB connected to a PC?. Which protocol do you use to connect?

Comment: It's true that Android device can present itself to PC as a photo camera, following the [Media Transport Protocol (MTP) or PictureTransfer Protocol (PTP)](https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/). To keep this view consistent, you must rebuild the MediaStore database after moving the photos.

Comment: On older devices, the USB Mass Storage protocol is available. This protocol effectively disconnects the SD card from your device when it becomes visible to PC. In the latter case, you cannot read, moreover manipulate, files on this storage while connected to PC.